# Can you add a custom button to the Utilities Panel in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

Just wondering if it's possible to add a custom button to the Utilities Panel in Xcode that you can drag it into a storyboard scene and have certain aspects already set, color, font/size, gradient etc.?

Comment: Check something like this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a custom `xib` file containing a view and its subviews. You then load the xib and stick the view in your interface in code, wherever and whenever you need it. Okay, you won't be able to see the effects of that within the storyboard, but it solves the problem extremely neatly.

Another possibility, if this is just about a button and nothing else, would be a UIButton *subclass* where the button configures *itself* to have the features you want.

But there is no way to drag-and-drop a custom button from the Object library into the design canvas. What's in the Object library is what's in the Object library and you can't change that.

Comment: Sorry kind of new to this, will that create a button that I can drag onto a storyboard scene from the bottom of the utilities panel from where all of the basic buttons, label, views etc are listed?

Comment: No, not at all. It will allow you to configure the custom button in the xib file and it will have those features ("certain aspects already set, color, font/size, gradient", as you say) wherever you use it.

Comment: Thanks, I had created a subclass for my buttons and that works fine, when I add the button I just pick that class with no issue and everything is implemented that I need. But my boss was asking if you can create a button to drag and drop in instead of having to pick the class each time. I was under the impression that you couldn't but figured this is a great place to ask.

Comment: You are right. You cannot drag and drop a button into the canvas such that it magically _is_ your button subclass. The button that you drag and drop into the canvas is, by definition, a standard UIButton. You cannot add custom objects to the Object library.

Comment: Thank you for confirming for me, I didn't want to tell him no, unless I was 100% sure. I've only been using XCode for a few months, making changes to an existing app, and am learning things as I go. Thanks again :)

Comment: But @jessicamele I don't really understand what the problem is, since if you have just _one_ button that is of the right class and configured as you like, you can just copy-and-paste it, can't you? Why does it matter whether it comes from the Object library? That is one reason I suggest making a model in a xib file (or you could even keep it in a spare location in the storyboard).

Comment: I think he was just curious if you could do that. In our case it's a button that will be at the bottom of a few VCs so he was wondering if the button could be placed in the object library and you could just drag it into each page to make it easier. I'm sure it can just be copied and pasted. I'm not fully familiar with a xib file. I created a custom class for making my UIButton then  in the identity inspector I reference that class for my buttons. Would the xib file be a better way to achieve this?